# read file name with fileSystem.createReader

Tags: javascript, cordova, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to access to a folder with some files using **cordova-file** and **fileSystem.createReader** method, and it works

The problem is that the function return me an object, and i want to see the **file name**.

**here my code**

```
       function listDir(path){
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
        function (fileSystem) {
          var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
          reader.readEntries(
            function (entries) {
              alert(entries);
            },
            function (err) {
              alert(err);
            }
          );
        }, function (err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      );
    } 
    listDir(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/pdf");
```

**here the response**

```
[object,object],[object,object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entries` is a list of [FileEntry](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova/file/fileentry/fileentry.html). 
Iterate on this list to have each `FileEntry` object, and retrieve file name using `myFileEntry.name`